# Uber ride sdk: uber ride request api

Tags: objective-c, uber-api

I am using uber ride SDK, using ride request widget I request a cab by setting current and destination location. But after click on request uber cab name it calculates fare then it shows missing payment methods. Below is the image of that error. How can I resolve this issue? Sowing this error:

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivaLs.png

Comment: This is likely a valid error. If this is the case, the user needs to add a payment method. The widget is a lightweight solution to easily plug-in Uber functionality. If the user does not have a valid payment method they should add one via riders.uber.com or in the Uber app.

Comment: @KyleDavis How to add these payment methods?

Comment: The user has to add them, e.g. https://help.uber.com/h/8f78dca4-9d75-44f1-bdc1-e90ca3da0319

Comment: @KyleDavis thank you so much. It's working for me.

Comment: No problem! I will add my comment as an answer then.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely a valid error. If this is the case, the user needs to add a payment method. The widget is a lightweight solution to easily plug-in Uber functionality. If the user does not have a valid payment method they should add one via riders.uber.com or in the Uber app.

The user has to add them, e.g. help.uber.com/h/8f78dca4-9d75-44f1-bdc1-e90ca3da0319